# p:toggleSwitch not setting the boolean value in bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primeface 7 and java 13 .

My issue is this when I use a p:toggleSwitch inside a p:dialog the set for the toggle switch no happening 
my dialog is as follows

```html
<p:dialog header="FOO" id="foo" widgetVar="foo" modal="true" styleClass="dialog-body"
 width="auto" height="auto" closeOnEscape="true">
 <h:form id="myform">
<p:toggleSwitch value="#{bean.booleanValue}" styleClass="toggleSwitch-right-50" immediate="true">
<p:ajax event="change" update="myform" onsuccess="foo.show()"/> </p:toggleSwitch>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}">
.........something......
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: So if you change the toggleSwitch to something else you don't get this error? (you might get another eror instead) Oh and you have three completely different unrelated things in your question. The warning is unrelated and effectively a clear statement of what is wrong but not visible in this code, setting the value not working is the second and the third is the javascript error. Please try to create an [mcve] for each issue and remember my previous statement about trying another component

Comment: oh and showing a dialog from a component within that dialog is weird

Comment: hi @Kukeltje thanks for your response,
these 3 issues came at same time , my major concern is to set the value from the toggleswitch and update the form.
hope you can help me in this

Comment: @Kukeltje the first dialog is just an id of the form it wont make any issues

Comment: like stated before, reduce your code  to a [mcve] until you have just this one problem. Then check with a different component. Still same problem? search for a generic 'jsf not updating value' question in stackoverflow (and sorry, I'm always in favour of helping others to become more effective developers and learn to make better use of 'searching' instead of providing direct solutions) e.g. reading all titles of >30 upvoted jsf Q/A would help already)

Comment: Oh and your comment does not make sense at all... the first dialog is an _**ID**_ of the form? Weird...

Comment: reduced my code  to a single problem

Comment: `onsuccess="foo.show()"` where should the JavaScript varialbe `foo` be defined?

Comment: But not a [mcve] (copy pasting just the code above in a new empty project does not run) And removing the panelGoup and/or dialog makes it work?

Comment: 1. Did you try accessing the `widgetVar` using new syntax `PF('foo').show()`. 2. I am not sure if you can use selector `update="myform"` since you are inside the form as a naming container. Did you try `update="@form"` and optional `process="id-of-toggleSwitch"`?